# JQuery Attribute to Lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, attr

I'm stumped why I'm getting this error. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing:

My HTML5 element with a custom attribute: < div data-id="somevalue">

```
var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');

alert(typeof dataId); // returns 'string'

alert(dataId.toLowerCase()); // TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is trace the jquery plugin `trace`?

Comment: Yeah, it's just a function for writing to the console. I've updated the code to be a little more clear.

Comment: Are you sure `$(this)` is actually referring to the `div` in question?

Comment: After update it looks pretty mystical.

Comment: Try to: alert((""+dataId).toLowerCase())

Comment: alert(typeof dataId.toLowerCase()); ?

Answer (score 0):

DOM element have not attribute data-id and attr('data-id') returns undefined.

EDIT: This code works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div data-id="AbA">Test</div>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("div").click(function() {
              var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
              alert(dataId.toLowerCase());
           });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In html5 you can set your own arbitrary attributes using the prefix "data-". The 'data-id' is an attribute of my own.

Comment: But it seems you haven't set it.

Answer (score 0):

you will be missing something check this it is full working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" >
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
            var dataId = $('#two').attr('data-id');
            alert(typeof dataId); // returns 'string'
            alert(dataId.toLowerCase()); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="two" data-id="TYTJNFCJF">Content</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery handles data attributes easily. Try

```
$(this).data('id');
```